# C - Assignment makes integer from pointer without cast

Tags: c, double-pointer

I have this code-fragment out of my programm:

```
typedef struct board_t{
   int x_pos;                 
   int y_pos;
   int size;
   int counter;        
   int** field;
};

int func(struct board_t* b){

[...]

int i;
for(i=b->size; i>=1; i--){    
    int y;
    for(y=b->size; y>=b->size; y--){
        b->field[i][y] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));   //warning here
        if(b->field[i][y] == NULL){
            printf("Failed to save memory...");
            return 1;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

field is a 2-dimensional array from type double-pointer. Now I get a warning "assignment makes integer from pointer without cast". Could someone explain this to me and how to fix it?

Comment: `b->field[i][y]` is an integer. You try to assign a `int*` to it. This code overall doesn't make sense, you should allocate all memory at once with a single malloc call.

Comment: You can't store a pointer to an int where an int is expected.

Comment: Is this code fragment supposed to be allocating space for the 2D array?

Comment: @dbush its supposed to store space for one entry of the array, would it be better to allocate all space at ones?

Comment: @Biswapriyo sry its supposed to be board_t

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @Lundin Thank you, thats what I was looking for :)

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not add a cast** to silence the (*badly worded*) warning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code isn't allocating space for the array correctly.

When you attempt to assign to `b->field[i][y]`, there are two problems with this.  First, this field has type `int`, but you're attempting to assign a pointer to it.  That's where the warning is coming from.  Second, `field` does not yet point anywhere, so `field[i]` is dereferencing an unintialized pointer.  You can't do that until you first assign something to `field`.

What you need to do is allocate space for an array of `int *` and assign it to `field` (the first dimension), then for each array member allocate space for an array of `int` and assign it to each member (the second dimension):

```
int i;
b->field = malloc(b->size * sizeof(*b->field));
if (!b->field) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
for (i=0; i<b->size; i++) {
    b->field[i] = malloc(b->size * sizeof(**b->field));
    if (!b->field[i]) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```